# Bot Framework SMS channel with iphone - Text messages are not working

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I have a working bot using the Emotion/Face API that takes a user provided image and returns back details about the image using the Face/Emotion API.

I configured the SMS channel using Twilio and everything works with android phones. The same with an iPhone does not even respond with no response texts coming back.

Am i missing any other configuration ?

Thank you 
AJ

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at your Twilio logs to see if the message is getting rejected by the carrier:  https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/logs

Comment: hi Lars, Yes I see errors in the twilio logs. Specifically these:
I see both 500 and 502 errors
In the response from the twilio number, I see this:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bad Gateway</h1>An upstream server returned an invalid response.
    </body>
</html>
Also in the error is this :
Error and Warning Notifications
Error
11200 HTTP retrieval failure
Description
An attempt to retrieve content from https://sms.botframework.com/api/sms returned the HTTP status code 500.

Comment: This only happens when requests come in from an iPhone . Android works without any errors or issues

Comment: Please ignore. I was using Twilio trial account and the phone has to be added as an approved number in the trial account to accept text messages. Was resolved. Thank you !